# What does $E(X)$ minimises $E(X-A)^2$ mean?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

> **Theorem:** The mean,  $E(X)$,  minimises $E(X-A)^2$ with respect to $A$.

I have no idea what this Theorem is trying to tell me. What does "minimises" mean in this context?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means considering all possible choices of $A$, choosing $A=E(X)$ is a minimum of the function $f(A) := E(X-A)^2$.

Or alternatively

$$E(X-A)^2 \geq E(X-E(X))^2 \text{ for every } A$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain maybe the use-fullness of such a theorem? Like intuitively, how would this be of use for us?

Comment: In what context did you find this theorem?

Comment: It is the beginning of my study of measures of central tendency, this was the first theorem given.

Comment: I am sure it will be used later, as it per se is not a very interesting result. It follows directly from the linearity of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of the function that for each input $A$ returns $E[X-A]^2$, then this function achieves its smallest value (minimum) for $A=E[X]$. You should be able to check that indeed $E[X-E[X]]^2=0$ on one side, and $E[X-A]^2\geq0$, for all real $A$'s.